# How to print the values of an object that is in an array list

Tags: java, object, arraylist, println

i have created an object from a method and put that object into an array list and now i want to print the values of the object in the array list, when I use System.out.println(objectname) i get the storage location of the object instead of the values

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

         Student tomas = new Student("tomas", "jordan");
            students.add(tomas);
            Student get = students.get(0);  
            System.out.println(get);
```

the result i get is Student@789ddfa3 the result i want is tomas,jordan

this is the student class below

public class Student {

```
public String fname;
public String lname;

//constructor
public Student(String fn,String ln){

    fname = fn;
    lname = ln;


}
}
```

Comment: you are getting object when you call students.get(0); how will it return you String !!!

Answer (score 4):

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) :

> You should always consider overriding the toString() method in your
>   classes.
>
> The Object's toString() method returns a String representation of the
>   object, which is very useful for debugging. The String representation
>   for an object depends entirely on the object, which is why you need to
>   override toString() in your classes.

Because you did'nt override the `toString()` method herited from the `Object` class, you get such an output :

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Override it in your `Student` class.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return fname+" "+lname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override `toString()` as

```
public String toString() {

return fname + lname;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Override the Object's class method toString()

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IDInput {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Student> students=new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(new Student("Om","Shankar"));
    System.out.println(students.get(0));
 }
}




 class Student {
    private final String mName;
    private final String lName;


    public Student(String inName, String inID) {
        mName = inName;
        lName = inID;

    }


    public String Called() {
        return (mName);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return mName+" "+lName  ;
    }
}`enter code here`
```